# Using PostgreSQL with Sequelize and Umzug in ES6+: Seeking Guidance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, umzug

I'm currently working on a project using PostgreSQL with Sequelize and Umzug in an ES6+ environment. However, I've encountered challenges with setting up the environment as I want to use ES6+. I'm seeking guidance on the best practices and potential solutions for integrating these technologies seamlessly.

## I tried below ones:

**This is my config.js**

```
// config/config.js
require('dotenv').config(); // Load environment variables

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: "postgres"
  },
  test: {
    dialect: "postgres"
  },
  production: {
    dialect: "postgres"
  }
};
```

**This is my database.js**

```
// config/database.js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// Load environment variables
dotenv.config();

const { DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME } = process.env;

if (!DB_HOST || !DB_PORT || !DB_USER || !DB_PASSWORD || !DB_NAME || DB_NAME.trim() === '') {
    throw new Error('Missing or invalid database environment variables.');
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: DB_HOST,
    port: DB_PORT,
    username: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASSWORD,
    database: DB_NAME,
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            require: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: false, // This line is particularly important for local development
        },
    },
    pool: {
        max: 5, // Maximum connections
        min: 0, // Minimum connections
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000, // Idle timeout in milliseconds
    },
});

const connectToPostgres = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error.message);
        // Optionally: Handle specific error scenarios (e.g., different error codes)

    }
};

const closeConnection = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.close();
        console.log('Database connection closed');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error closing database connection:', error.message);
    }
};

export { sequelize, connectToPostgres, closeConnection };
```

**// migrations/umzug.js**

```
// migrations/umzug.mjs
import { Umzug, SequelizeStorage } from 'umzug';
import sequelize from '../config/database.mjs'; // Importing Sequelize instance
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'; // Importing the fileURLToPath function from the 'url' module
import path, { dirname } from 'path'; // Importing the path and dirname functions from the 'path' module

// Convert import.meta.url to a file path
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

// Define the path to the migrations directory
const migrationsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'migrations');

// Create Umzug instance
const migrator = new Umzug({
    migrations: {
        glob: ['*.{js,cjs,mjs}', { cwd: migrationsPath }],
    },
    context: sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
    storage: new SequelizeStorage({
        sequelize,
    }),
    logger: console,
});

// Run Umzug CLI
migrator.runAsCLI();
```

Comment: what is the error or problem

Comment: when i try :`npx umzug create create-books`
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/chin-2/.npm/_logs/2024-02-06T06_32_44_408Z-debug-0.log

Comment: are using CLI? your command is wrong for cli usage. Read the docs here: https://github.com/sequelize/umzug

Comment: tried this one but it seems like some compability issues showing :`node umzug.mjs create --name new-migration-2.mjs`
import { sequelize } from '../config/database.js';
         ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'sequelize' not found. The requested module '../config/database.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '../config/database.js';
const { sequelize } = pkg;

Comment: you are mixing up ES6 and commonjs syntaxes

Comment: by removing {} in `import sequelize from '../config/database.js` got it but when i tried `node migrations/umzug.mjs create --name new-migration-2.mjs --folder migrations` 
{
  event: 'created',
  path: 'migrations/2024.02.06T09.33.27.new-migration-2.mjs'
}

_Error: Expected migrations/2024.02.06T09.33.27.new-migration-2.mjs to be a pending migration but it wasn't! Pending migration paths: . You should investigate this. Use --skip-verify to bypass this error._

Comment: add `--skip-verify `

Comment: tried this also and it's working but is it best practice to follow or should I make some changes?